# Отслеживание изменений input в partial view .NET

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, mvc, razor

Постараюсь разложить детально. 
Имеется **View**, в которой в зависимости от выбора пользователя подгружаю **PartialView**. В этом частичном представлении есть **инпут**. 
Есть необходимость обрабатывать его **посимвольное изменение** и при этом брать значение, которое ввел пользователь для подгрузки частичного представления.

```
$(function() {
    $('#FormingType').change(function() {
        var id = $(this).val();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("FormingType")/' + id,
            success: function(data) {
                $('#formingTypeBlock').replaceWith(data); // заменяем содержимое присланным частичным представлением
            }
        });
    });
});

$(function () {
    $('#tetr').on('keyup input', function () {
        var tetrCount = $('#tetr').val();
        var id = $('#Format').val();
        console.log(tetrCount);
        console.log(id);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("SetSewingPrice")/' + id + '/' + tetrCount,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                $('#blockPrice').empty();
                $('#blockPrice').text(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Дело в том, что когда вторую функцию вставляю внутрь partial view изменения отслеживаются, но скрипт не видит **#FormingType**(Который в основной вьюшке), а когда вставляю эту функцию в основную вьюшку - функция на изменение инпута не реагирует.

Вот код основной вьюшки:

```
@Html.DropDownList("FormingType", "--Выберите тип формировки блока--")
<div id="formingTypeBlock"></div>
```

Вот партиал:

```
<div id="formingTypeBlock">
<h1>@Model.Name тип формировки блока</h1>
<form name="block" method="POST">
    <input type="text" id="tetr"/>
    <br/>

    <span id="blockPrice"></span>
</form>
```

**Подскажите, что не так? Уже несколько дней голову ломаю!**

Comment: почитайте про то как привязывать события к динамически создаваемым объектам, например `$("#formingTypeBlock").on('keyup', "#tetr", function(){ })`, если при вашем `ReplaceWith()` этот  обработчик сам не сбрасывается, иначе еще вверх по DOM привязывать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил этот вопрос давненько, дело было в том, что **при подгрузке частичного представления** скрипт **ничего не знал об объектах находящихся внутри**. Для того, чтобы исправить такую ситуацию обработчики изменений я навешиваю **не** в общем скрипте **на document ready**, а при появлении этого частичного представления. То есть на выбор пользователя, исходя из которого подгружается partial.